After installing medusa strapi, i get an error when i run npm run develop to start strapi
Describe the bug
A clear and concise description of what the bug is.
I have the medusa backend running 100% with no issues. I am also able to run the medusa frontend and they both communicate properly.
After installing strapi for medusa as specified in the documentation https://docs.medusajs.com/plugins/cms/strapi I get the following error when I try to run the command
npm run develop inside the package/medusa-strapi folder
error: alter table "public"."product_tags_products_links" add constraint "product_tags_products_links_fk" foreign key ("product_tag_id") references "public"."product_tags" ("id") on delete CASCADE - there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "product_tags"
To Reproduce
Steps to reproduce the behavior:

cone https://github.com/SGFGOV/medusa-strapi-repo.git inside an already existing medusa backend
Instal medusa-strapi, install dependencies by running yarn install
After dependency installation is successfull, run the command npm run develop to start strapi server
See error

Expected behavior
Strapi Server should run successfully after running the npm run develop command from the medusa-strapi folder
Screenshots
*Desktop (please complete the following information):**

OS: [e.g. iOS] - MAC
Browser [e.g. chrome, safari] - Chrome
Medusa Version - 1.20.9
in Medusa-Strapi Package  -  "@strapi/strapi": "4.13.1",
In Medusa Package   - "medusa-plugin-strapi-ts": "^5.0.22",
Node Version [e.g. 22] - 18

Additional context
To resolve the issue, I added the id field to product_tags and executed the command but the error persisted
ALTER TABLE product_tags 
ADD CONSTRAINT unique_product_tag_id UNIQUE (id);

Kindly direct me on why I am getting this error
Screenshots





Your screenshot shows a different error, Key columns "product_tag_id" and "id" are of incompatible types: integer and character varying. That's pretty clear - product_tags.id and product_tag_id must be the same column type

@ceejayoz i did not create any of the databasse table. All i did was to run a fresh medusa create project and seed. So I am confued why i get the error when i try installing strapi. Can you help with the command to adjust any medusa table ?

Why does your question contain irrelevant sentences like If applicable, add screenshots to help explain your problem -- please leave stuff like that out and focus on asking a clear question.

Apparently the issue was due to the fact that I was pointing the strapi DB to the same DB use by my medusa backend.
To resolve this, I provided a separate DB to Strapi and Medusa and Puff, the error when away

Apparently the issue was due to the fact that I was pointing the strapi DB to the same DB use by my medusa backend.
To resolve this, I provided a separate DB in my Strapi config and a different DB for my Medusa backend and Puff, the error when away.
HINT
By integrating Strapi into Medusa, you can benefit from powerful features in your Medusa ecommerce store, including detailed product CMS details, two-way sync, an easy-to-use interface to use for static content and pages, and much more
